# React JS Max updates exceeded error when setting State in a conditional, via a context provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, state

Currently I am working inside of a functional component, and trying to set state based on a prop that's getting passed into it.

```
if (prop){
 contextProvider.updateText()
}
```

Context provider code

```
const updateText = () => {
 setButtonState({text: "testing"})
}
```

this results in

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Any advice on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you add full code ? Also the error message correctly explains the problem, you are updating state in infinite loop. You need to check condition

Comment: Yea I recognize the problem, just rerendering infinitely. Im not sure how to resolve, as I need to set the state based on this prop that's getting passed in. What part of the code would you like to see? The files are quite large, and this was the simplest form of the issue.

Ive called the context provider func that I created from other files that also reference the context provider, and it worked fine. So I just assume its because of where I am calling it in the code. Could I use useEffect somehow to resolve this? The prop is basically "If an item is selected"

Comment: Maybe you can add full component code or atleast lifecycle code